# Facebook APP [and js api] not showing any of the friends

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, web

I am trying to create a facebook web app, but am unable to get any of the friends through facebook javascript API. What I basically want my app to do is that it will ask a user to login and then after authorization, his/her all the friends{weather using the app or not} should be displayed.

Is it possible to get friends who don't use the app at all?
If so, please tell me how! :)

img : http://postimg.org/image/9r959i38n/

code in my app:

```
FB.api('/me/friends',function(res){
   console.log(res.data[0].name); //just sample output
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 13):

`/me/friends` now only returns friends who are also using your app - https://developers.intern.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_graph_api

See the full document for new APIs that might solve your problem instead.

Answer (score 1):

Here's two new APIs for:

Inviting friends - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/invitable_friends

Tagging friends -https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/taggable_friends

Answer (score 0):

With the release of [version 2.0 of the API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/versions),

> In Graph API v2.0, access to `/me/friends` is no longer part of the default (public_profile) 
>   permissions. We now require you to ask for the new permission `user_friends`. With this
>   permission, **`/me/friends` now returns the person's friends who are also using the app.**

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_permissions

### Solution (temporary)

You can use version 1.0 till April 30th 2016.

```
http://graph.facebook.com/v1.0/
```

Opinion: This change will put an end for spam apps